# Wordpress Plugin...return name of page

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to teach myself a little about writing Wordpress plugins and things and I am running into problem I can't seem to figure out.  I guess I'm not sure exactly what I need to change here.  The code below returns the domain name "www.mydomain.com" for the plug in.  I'm trying to get it to include the page name as well.  I'm assuming that the "site_url()" is not the proper function to be using really, but can't figure out what would be used in place.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
$site_url = wp_parse_url( site_url() );
define( 'HOSTNAME', $site_url['host'] );
```

Comment: $pagename doesn't work? Its a wp global var to get page name

Comment: And also the title of the page usually is the page name therefore. $page_title = $wp_query->post->post_title;  should return the page name

Comment: Masivuye...would like the entire URL, not just the page name or page title. If the page has a parent page, that would be reflected in the URL structure and so I'd want that to be passed through as well... So 'www.example.com/parent/pagename'

Comment: U hv to use permalink() to get the page url